Explain this step in proof of $(AB)^{−1}=B^{−1}A^{−1}$.
I was going through a proof about the inverse of two invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ the proof was about that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, lets quickly go through that proof;
$(AB)(AB)^{-1} = I$
$A^{-1}(AB)(AB)^{-1} = A^{-1}$
$IB(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}$
$B^{-1}B(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$
$I(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$
$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$
my question is about the third last step when we multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ why in the $RHS$ we write $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and not like $A^{-1}B^{-1}$, this question arose to me as my whole life i have seen that when we multiply both sides by some number(for eg $a$) we write $a$ after the numbers that were already on that side
i mean like this:
$2 = 2$
$2a = 2a$
then why do we do it like this for the matrices?

You are multiplying on the left by $B^{-1}$. How will it go to the right?

@geetha290krm its multiplied both sides

Put something useful in the title. People read the title to see quickly if they might be able to help you. Help people help you.

@ThomasAndrews what title should i keep then?

Unlike numbers, matrix multiplication is not generally commutative, so it could make a difference which side you’re multiplying; in this case multiply by $B^{-1}$ on the left to cancel $B$

@J.W.Tanner yes and what decides that it should be done this way and not the other?

"Explain this step in proof of $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}.$"

It must be the same order on both sides. Given $X=Y$, you can conclude $ZX=ZY$ or $XZ=YZ$ but not necessarily $ZX=YZ$ or $XZ=ZY$.

When you go from $x=y$ to $f(x)=f(y)$, you can't instead go to $f(x)=g(y)$ for a different function $g$. The function $x\mapsto Bx$ is very different from $x\mapsto xB$.

@J.G. so we can't multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ and write $B^{-1}$ after already present matrices?

In general for matrices $A$ and $B$, it is not true that $AB=BA$. Hence, if you have an equation $X=Y$, you can only conclude $AX=AY$ or $XA=YA$. In the proof when you have
$$B(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}$$
you can multiply by $B^{-1}$ in two ways:

pre-multiply and get $B^{-1}B(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.
post-multiply and get $B(AB)^{-1}B^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$.

Both of these are correct, but only the first one helps us in the proof, and gives us $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.
Hope this helps. :)

but if i post multiply instead wouldn't it prove that $(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$

@AmitVerma: It will not. Post multiplying gives you $$B(AB)^{-1}B^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$$You cannot simplify the LHS to $(AB)^{-1}$.

but the matrix multiplication does follow the associative law?

Yes, it does follow it.

@AmitVerma: Associativity implies that $(XY)Z=X(YZ)$, and not $XYZ=XZY$.

so the multiplicative order matter oh yeah just remembered thats what commutative law says thanks :)

When you have an equality $a=b$, you can deduce another equality by applying the same transformation (say $f$) to $a$ and $b$, i.e., $f(a) = f(b)$. (Because $a$ and $b$ are the same thing, so if you transform them in the same way, you still get identical things.)
So, you can multiply by $B^{-1}$ either on the left or on the right, but you must choose the same (left or right) for the two sides of the equation.
You have $B (A B)^{-1} = A^{-1}$. If you multiply by $B^{-1}$ on the right, you get $B (A B)^{-1} B^{-1} = A^{-1} B^{-1}$, which is valid, but is of no use to complete the proof. Instead, of you multiply by $B^{-1}$ on the left, you get $B^{-1} B (A B)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$, which is useful because you can simplify $B^{-1} B$ to get $(A B)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$.
By the way, this is not actually a full, valid proof that for $A$ and $B$ invertible, the inverse of $A B$ is $B^{-1} A^{-1}$. The reason is that it starts by assuming $(A B)^{-1}$ exists, but not all matrices are invertible, so this requires a proof.
Instead a valid proof is the following: Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible matrices. Then we have
$(A B) (B^{-1} A^{-1}) = A I A^{-1} = A A^{-1} = I$
and
$(B^{-1} A^{-1}) (A B) = B^{-1} I B = B^{-1} B = I$.
(NB: To prove $Q$ is the inverse of $P$ you a priori need to prove $PQ = I$ and $QP = I$. It turns out that $PQ = I$ also implies $QP = I$, but usually you don't see this in your very first contact with matrices.)

the perfect answer, sorry i have already marked someones else's as the accepted one :(
